# SCOM 2016 monitor log file dynamically?

Tags: scom

I have a requirement to monitor a particular java string in a logfile whose name changes with date, for ex. D:\Logs\logfile-DDMMYYYY.log. I want to get a alert if this string is detected in the log. Can someone help me that?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Script is your best way for accomplish that, if it is an linux machine you can wrote a perl\bash script. if you need to monitor Windows machine you can use VBScript.

If you prefer not dealing with scripts, you can use NiCE Excellnet & Free Log File Monitoring MP: http://www.nice.de/log-file-monitoring-scom-nice-logfile-mp/ But i don't sure if theirs mp supports monitoring wildcards log file names.

Answer (score 0):

SCOM can monitor log files dynamically. You should monitor log directory D:\Logs with log file pattern logfile-????????.log.